# What's wrong here that I can't bind service in android

Tags: android, service

It is returning `NullPointerException` when I click play button where I want to bind the stop button with the value of getCount() method which is in the Service class which should return 1, it is crashing when I am clicking play button.
This is the activity class:

```
public class MainMP3 extends Activity{
Button stop;
static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
Button data_display;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mp3interface);
    startService(new Intent(MainMP3.this, ServiceMP3.class));

    stop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

    // to stop service 
    //stopService(new Intent(MainMP3.this, ServiceMP3.class));

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    button.setOnClickListener(new StartClick());  

}

  private ServiceMP3 service = null;

    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override  // Called when connection is made
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName cName, IBinder binder) {
            service = ((ServiceMP3.SlowBinder)binder).getService();
        }
        @Override   //
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName cName) {
            service = null;
        }
    };  

    private class StartClick implements View.OnClickListener {      
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int data = service.getCount();
            stop.setText(Integer.toString(data));
        }
    }
       }
```

and here is Service:

```
public class ServiceMP3 extends Service {

 private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
 private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
 private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
 private int currentPosition;
 int count=1;
 private NotificationManager nm;
 private static final int NOTIFY_ID = R.layout.song;


    public int getCount() {return count;}

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        BindAllSongs();

        System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH+ songs.get(currentPosition));

        for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(songs.get(i).toString());
        }

        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            //          playSong(MEDIA_PATH+ songs.get(currentPosition));

            //          Thread thr = new Thread(null, work, "Play Song");
             //         thr.start();

            // Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             //         player = MediaPlayer.create(ServiceMP3.this, R.raw.test);
            //          player.start();
            //          player.setLooping(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;  
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        nm.cancel(NOTIFY_ID);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public void BindAllSongs() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         //To hold all the audio files from SDCARD
        File fileListBeforeFiltering = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        //Filter all the MP# format songs to list out
        //Checking for the MP3 Extension files existence 
            if (fileListBeforeFiltering.listFiles(new    FilterFilesByMp3Extension()).length > 0) 
            {
                //Loop thru all the files filtered and fill them in SongsList view that we have 
                //Defined above.
                for (File file : fileListBeforeFiltering.listFiles(new FilterFilesByMp3Extension())) 
                {
                    //Adding all filtered songs to the list
                        songs.add(file.getName());
                }

        }
    }

     void playSong(String file) {
        try {





                mp.setDataSource(file);

                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();

                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                             nextSong();
                     }
             });

        } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
       }


     void nextSong() {
        // Check if last song or not
        if (++currentPosition >= songs.size()) {
                currentPosition = 0;
                nm.cancel(NOTIFY_ID);
        } else {
                playSong(MainMP3.MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(currentPosition));
        }


}

     void prevSong() {
        if (mp.getCurrentPosition() < 3000 && currentPosition >= 1) {
                playSong(MainMP3.MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(--currentPosition));
        } else {
                playSong(MainMP3.MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(currentPosition));
        }
}


    Runnable work = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

             while (true) { 

                System.out.println("Runnable method....");

            }

        }

    };


    private final IBinder binder = new SlowBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public class SlowBinder extends Binder {
        ServiceMP3 getService() {
            return ServiceMP3.this;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: why can't you bind it? explain or paste the logcat please.

Comment: in LogCat it is showing NullPointerException!

Comment: Ok. So there is your problem. Debug and check the line that is throwing the NPE.

Comment: I have one question, Do I need to bind if I only call the method of the Service SoundPlay(String str) from the Activity onclickbutton??

Can I just create an instance of Service and call the method SoundPlay() and to pass here an string, will this work or not? Or anyhow I have to bind ?

Answer (score 5):

First try to replace

> startService(new Intent(MainMP3.this, ServiceMP3.class));

on

> bindService(new Intent(MainMP3.this, ServiceMP3.class));

Read please: [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)